# echo cancellation for FMS or Red5?

Tags: audio, echo, red5, flash-media-server, duplex

It's unavailable that since 2008, echo cancellation has been requested to ADOBE and they just have done nothing. They just promised (3 months ago) they will release the feature in june with the 10.3 player.

I need a solution now, can't wait until June. has any one tried a server side solution for this? I found this company: http://www.solicall.com/index.html, they are in Israel, I contacted them and I'm waiting or their response.

I basically need full duplex audio communication between 2 flash clients. It can be FMS or Red5 (or any other technology) as long as the users can talk without headsets and no echo.

I saw there are several question about the same subject, most of them focused to client solutions, and unfortunately without solution.

Any suggestions / ideas?
Tks.

Comment: Is this a *programming* question ?

Answer (score 0):

AEC has been available since Flash Player 10.3 and Air 2.7. Here's how you use it: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/acoustic-echo-cancellation.html
If you want to do AEC on the server-side you'd have to use something like Xuggler.